# Question that can not be solve analytically .

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, logarithms, systems-of-equations

You can know that the solution of this non-linear simultaneous equations is y=2 and x=3; but the question is : How can mathematically ( algebraically ) find this.
\begin{array}{lcl} x^y & = & 9 \\ y^x & = & 8 \end{array}

Comment: You trying to solve this system for x > 0, y > 0 real and not only for integers, right?

Comment: Yes.. in general...

Comment: @henry: unless we use something like LambertW functions, I don't see any way of "solving" this in general.

Comment: @SergioParreiras you can try to use it,So if we could solve it partially this will be progress for the general case...

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to solving

$$ x^{a^x} = b $$

which, I think, has no analytic solution.

Answer (score -1):

Ln both equations to get:

$\ln x^y = \ln 9$ and $\ln y^x = \ln 8$

They then become $y \ln x = \ln 9$ and $x \ln y = \ln 8$

Solving for $x$ and $y$ you get

$y = \frac{\ln 9}{\ln x}$ and $x = \frac{\ln 8}{\ln y}$

Substituting $x = \frac{\ln 8}{\ln y}$ into the first equation you get

$y = \frac{\ln 9}{\ln(\ln 8/\ln y)}$

Doing the same for $x$, you get

$x = \frac{\ln 8}{\ln(\ln 9/\ln x)}$

...?

Comment: Are you assuming that $x$ and $y$ must be integers?

Comment: not necessary integer , but solution of course will be integer,,, I mean if you look at the graph.. the solution is integer.. but

Comment: Thanks @zhoe.. but we can not do in this way since in the second step of your solution is wrong... since the only case your assertion will be true if the base is equal , but we  one of the bas is $x$ and the second is $3$ which there is no guarantee to be equal.. but thanks good try

Comment: @zhoe : this is right only if we assume before solving the problem that $x$ and $y$ are integers, which is not the case.

Comment: I understand..I am quite rusty with my maths. My first thought was to ln both sides and then equate...Would that be correct?

Comment: @zhoe : we can use logs, say: $y \ln(x)=\ln(9)$ and $ x \ln(y) =\ln(8)$ we can eliminate y to get $x \left(\ln(\ln(9))-\ln(\ln(x))\right)=\ln(8)$ but this gives a non-linear equation in $x$ that I don't see any general way of solving (without knowing the answer beforehand).

Comment: @CalvinLin Let assume that $x$ and $y$ are integers... do we have solution for this case.